# SSRS 2008 - The permissions granted to user 'computer\username' are insufficient for performing this operation. (rsAccessDenied)

Tags: ssrs-2008

I've looked through several other questions here and on other sites regarding this issue, and none of them have solved the problem I'm running into.  Hopefully I'm just overlooking something simple.

The scenario that I'm running into involves a new installation of SSRS 2008 on Windows Server 2008 R2.  After finishing the installation, I cannot access the Web Service URL.  When I try to do so, it gives me the rsAccessDenied error.  The user that it is stating as not having enough permissions is specifically **MY username**.

I also cannot access the "full" version of Report Manager.  Specifically, I do not have access to the Site Settings link, or the ability to upload reports.

A little background.  My user is a member of the Administrators group on the server, and is also a system administrator in SQL server.  The user is also the dbo for the Reporting Services database.  I am trying to access the Web Service URL and the Report Manager from the server itself, not across the internet at this point.

I've tried the following:

- Run IE as administrator.
- Added the server to the list of trusted sites.
- The service account for Reporting Services is the built in Network Service account.
- Made sure that the Network Services account has access to the ReportServer and ReportServerTempDB databases.
- Made sure that Network Services had read and read & execute access to the Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services folder structure.

Any information would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that the problem was with the administrators group that my user was part of.  I was part of the group \Administrators, but *not* part of BUILTIN\Administrators.  BUILTIN\Administrators was the group administration that SSRS had set up by default.

After this was taken care of, everything started working just fine.

Comment: Or you can visit this article for more details [link](http://www.gotknowhow.com/articles/reportserver-permissions-granted-are-insufficient-for-performing-this-operation-rsaccessdenied)

Answer (score 3):

I've tried all of this also, but finally disabling UAC on Windows 7 is what did the trick.

I:

1. Disabled UAC
2. Rebooted PC
3. Run IE as Admin
4. Added my local Reporting Services server to the list of trusted sites
5. Added my Windows user as Content Manager on Folder Configuration
6. Added my Windows user as System Administrator on Site Settings.
7. After testing I had access, I enabled UAC again, rebooted my PC and voilá!!

It worked!

Answer (score 0):

Choosing "run as administrator" when starting my browser fixed the problem for me. Admittedly this doesn't seem like a long term solution.